# What happened when reduce writes data into hdfs?

Tags: java, mapreduce, hdfs

In the paper of Google MapReduce, fault tolerance about reduce only mentioned the completed reduce task.

So, I want to know, what happened if reduce is in-progress state when error occured?

If data directly write into hdfs during reduce in-progess state, what do we do about these data already written into hdfs?